# Javafx Layout problem with VBox & HBoxes

Tags: javafx, hbox

When I run the following, I noticed spacing between nodes; My research revealed that - 
1) If I do not add any text to win1 via setwininfo, then there is no problem.
2) When I include this code in a larger app, and when a button click is reveived from   some where else, mysteriously the spacing gets corrected.
3) I tried binding the win1 & win2 nodes to content of scene - but no luck.

def mainframew : Integer = 250;
def mainframeh : Integer = 500;

class CtrlWindow extends CustomNode {

```
var wininfo : String;
var fsize : Integer;
var width : Integer;

public function setWinInfo(info : String) {
    wininfo = info;
}

override protected function create () : Node {
    var win = Group {
                                    content: [
                                         VBox {
                                                content: [
                                                    Text {
                                                            font : Font {
                                                                    size: fsize
                                                            }

                                                            content : bind wininfo

                                                            textAlignment : TextAlignment.CENTER  // did not work
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                        }

                                        Rectangle {
                                                width: width, height: 25
                                                fill: Color.TRANSPARENT
                                                strokeWidth : 2
                                                stroke : Color.SILVER
                                        }

                                    ]
                            }

    return win;
}
```

}

public function run(args : String[]) {

var win1 = CtrlWindow{fsize:14, width:mainframew};
   var win2 = CtrlWindow{fsize:14, width:mainframew};

win1.setWinInfo("The spacing between these nodes");
   win2.setWinInfo("corrects itself after receiving an event");

Stage {

```
title : "MyApp"
scene: Scene {
    width: mainframew
    height: mainframeh
    content: [
                        VBox {
                               spacing: 0
                               content: [
                                            HBox {
                                                    content: win1
                                            }

                                            HBox {
                                                    content: win2
                                            }
                                ]
                        }
            ]
}
}
```

Comment: Try formatting your code: indent only with 4 spaces. Currently it is completely unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using JavaFX 1.3, the issue may be related to the preferred sizes of the CtrlWindow. You may want to use a layoutInfo to set a common preferred size, otherwise, the preferred size will change with the content of the two CtrlWindow nodes.

Something like:

```
win1 = CtrlWindow{
        fsize:14
        layoutInfo : LayoutInfo { width: mainframew, minHeight: 50 }
   }
```

When you merely set the width (without a bind), this will be reset to the preferred size in the HBox layout.